# Number of words such that no letter appears twice and no letter is followed by the next letter in the sequence.

Tags: combinatorics

An alien language has n letters $b_1, . . . , b_n$. For some $k < n/2$ assume that all words
formed by any of the k letters (written left to right) are meaningful. These words are
called k-words. Such a k-word is considered sacred if:

i) no letter appears twice and,

ii) if a letter $b_i$ appears in the word then the letters $b_{i−1}$ and $b_{i+1}$ do not appear. (Here
$b_{n+1} = b_1$ and $b_0 = b_n$.)

What is the total number of sacred k-words?

Can someone please provide a hint about how to start/think about this problem? I've been trying a lot but can't think of anything. (I only want hints and would like to complete the problem on my own.)

Comment: It might be helpful to think about seating $k$ people around a circular table with $n$ seats such that no one sits next to each other [without an empty seat in between]. This is related to your original problem.

Comment: Extending angryavian's comment, first suppose that the chairs are positioned in a row, rather than a circular table.  Then, the problem can be started by **extending** the Stars and Bars problem (as discussed at https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) so that each gap except the leftmost and rightmost gap must be **positive**.  This is easily resolved by assuming that the sum must be $(n+2)$, rather than $n$, so that now you can require that **all** variables are positive. ...see next comment

Comment: Requiring that for example all $k$ variables are positive and sum to $(n+2)$ **bijects** to requiring that $k$ non-negative variables sum to $(n+2-k)$, which is directly addressed by Stars and Bars.  As for converting the problem of chairs seated in a **row** to chairs seated in a **circle**, my spatial-visualization intuition is so weak that I can't help here.

Comment: Your title is misleading.  Rather than saying no letter is followed by the next letter of the sequence, you should say that no two consecutive letters appear in the word.

Comment: **Warning**: I am generally inept at chairs in a circle problems vs chairs in a row problems, so I am on shaky ground here.  That being said, with respect to my previous comments, arbitrarily select Person-X to be construed as the person at "12-O-clock" with the other people being positioned (for example) clockwise when viewed from above.  There must be a positive gap between all people.  Now "biject" the possible placements into the corresponding placements in a row, where every gap (except the very leftmost gap) must be positive.  ...see next comment.

Comment: The reason that the leftmost gap can be zero, is that the rightmost gap is already required to be positive.  This analogizes to the row problem of k variables summing to $n$, where all but the 1st variable must be positive, and the 1st variable must be non-negative.  This then **bijects** into the problem of k variables (all of which must be positive) summing to (n+1), rather than n.  This then **bijects** into the standard problem of k non-negative variables summing to (n+1-k). ...see next comment

Comment: The reason that I (somewhat illegibly) made this a series of comments, rather than a *hint/answer*, is because I am on shaky ground here.  I can't couch this as an answer because I am unsure of my analysis.  It does **seem** however to be accurate.

Comment: The question is quite similar to finding number of k element subsets of the set  {1,2,3,...,n} such that no two numbers in the subset are consecutive.

Comment: @user2661923 really appreciate your comments. I thought of it a bit differently and tried to find all the possible sequences of "gaps" that would be there. If $b_1b_3b_5$ is a word for $k=3, n=7$ then the corresponding gaps would be $(1,1,2)$ and the sum of the gaps would always add to $1+1+2=4=n-k$ so the equation I got was to find solution of k-postive variables summing to $n-k$ since the gaps are $\geq 1$. Then we can arrange the gaps in $(k-1)!$ ways assuming the first letter is fixed. I'm unable to count the total number of such words. The answer: $n(k-1)!$ $n-k-1 \choose k-1$. Why n?

Comment: But if you got $n (k-1)! { {n-k-1} \choose {k-1}}$, that is the correct answer.

Comment: and I used similar logic.

Comment: @MathLover that is the given answer. I don't understand why we're multiplying by  $n$. How does multiplying by $n$ give us the total number of such words? I got $(k-1)!$ $n-k-1 \choose k-1$.

Comment: because you choose the first letter and that can be done in $n$ ways. Any of the letters can be the first letter. I can post my solution.

Comment: @MathLover ohh, I get it now. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @MathLover Please post your analysis as an answer.  I am very curious how "far off the rails" the analysis in my comments was.  I'll be able to determine that after I study your answer against my subconscious backdrop of Stars and Bars.

Comment: @user2661923 sure, just posted.

Answer (score 2):

Given the condition that no two consecutive letters ($\, b_1, b_n \,$ considered
consecutive), the upper bound on the length of words will be $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor, \frac{n}{2}$ for even $n$ and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ for odd $n$. **So $k \lt \frac{n}{2}$ given in the question works.**

We can choose the first letter from any of the $n$ letters (in $^nc_1$ ways). Now given the condition of no two consecutive letters, if we have $k$ letters placed on a circle, we will have to have at least one missed letter between any two neighbouring letters. As there are $k$ letters placed, there are $k$ gaps between them and we need to find ways to sum number of missed letters in these $k$ gaps to $(n-k)$ missed letters such that there is at least one missed letter in each gap.

This is simply a stars and bars problem and the number of ways is ${n-k-1} \choose {k-1}$.

So, $n \times {{n-k-1} \choose {k-1}} \, $ gives us all combinations of $k$ letters meeting the condition.

Now these $k$ letters can be permuted in $(k-1)! \,$ ways.

So, number of distinct k-words (for any given $ k) = n \times (k-1)! \times{{n-k-1} \choose {k-1}} \, $

Total number of meaningful words for all $k = \sum \limits_{k = 1}^{\lt n/2} n \times (k-1)! \times{{n-k-1} \choose {k-1}} \, $

Comment: +1 elegant, thanks.  Minor glitch: re the statement of the query, when $n$ even, $k = \frac{n}{2}$ seems to be **disallowed**, since a $k$-word is only defined for $k < \frac{n}{2}.$

Comment: @user2661923 yes you are right. As per the question $k$ is defined $\le \frac{n}{2}$ but I can meet the condition of no two consecutive letters with $= < \frac{n}{2}$. But I will edit given the question. Btw I was going through your analysis. It seems alright to me. This problem can actually be seen as letters in a row except giving gap either on the leftmost side or rightmost side which is there in your analysis.

Comment: @Tapi - to both Tapi and Math Lover : 2nd possible glitch : posted query may be *ambiguous*.  Re :"What is the total number of sacred k-words", is this asking for $f(k)$ where $1 \leq k < (n/2)$ [or $\cdots... \leq (n/2)$], or $\sum_{\text{permissible}~k} f(k)$?

Comment: @user2661923 I think the question may be asking for a given value of $k$. The last line was just an extra :)

Comment: @user2661923 yes, it's asking for a given value of k, what is the total number of sacred k-words.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hint which leads to my solution:

Count the number of $A\subset\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ such that $|A|=k$ and there isn't any pair $(i;j)$, $i,j\in A$ with $|i-j|=1$ It is much easier to count sets and arranging the elements will give you the total amount. Comment here if you want the full sol. Good luck!

Comment: @Tapi In light of Tapi's latest comment, please **go for it**.  If looks okay, you will spare me from trying to "Enter the (circular) Dragon".

Comment: @Vlad please share your solution and I'd be glad if you could clarify my doubt posted as a comment above.

Comment: I tried to find out what you asked and I got $n-k+1 \choose k$